# AndroidManifest.xml error android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest, capacitor

I am building an Ionic 6 project using Capacitor. My AndroidManifest.xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.mycomp.mycomp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/mycomp_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/mycomp_icon"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
            android:name="com.mycomp.mycomp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

             <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="mycomp" android:pathPrefix="/signup-verification" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>


    </application>
    

</manifest>
```

My build.gradle file looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    namespace 'com.mycomp.mycomp'
    compileSdkVersion 31
    
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycomp.mycomp"
        minSdkVersion 31
        targetSdkVersion 31
        buildToolsVersion "31.0.0"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        aaptOptions {
             // Files and dirs to omit from the packaged assets dir, modified to accommodate modern web apps.
             // Default: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/282e181b58cf72b6ca770dc7ca5f91f135444502/tools/aapt/AaptAssets.cpp#61
            ignoreAssetsPattern '!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    namespace 'com.mycomp.mycomp'

    // Enable support for Android 12
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.2.0'
            force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:19.2.0'
            force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:19.2.0'
            force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:19.2.0'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir{
        dirs '../capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/libs', 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$androidxAppCompatVersion"
    implementation "androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:$androidxCoordinatorLayoutVersion"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-splashscreen:$coreSplashScreenVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-android')
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$androidxJunitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$androidxEspressoCoreVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins')
}

apply from: 'capacitor.build.gradle'

try {
    def servicesJSON = file('google-services.json')
    if (servicesJSON.text) {
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    logger.info("google-services.json not found, google-services plugin not applied. Push Notifications won't work")
}
```

I have the following code that is run when I get the error.

```
import { Filesystem } from '@capacitor/filesystem';
import { FilePicker } from '@capawesome/capacitor-file-picker';
...

async getImage(oldURL: string) {
  
    await Filesystem.requestPermissions(); // Requesting Permissions

    const file = await FilePicker.pickImages({
      multiple: false,
    });

}
```

In Android Studio, when I run my project, Sometimes it will ask for permissions to open a file then fail with the following error, and sometimes it just fails right away with the error:

```
File: http://localhost/main.js -
Line 1 - Msg: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise):
Error: Missing the following permissions in AndroidManifest.xml:
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

at returnResult (http://localhost/:771:32)
at win.androidBridge.onmessage (http://localhost/:746:21)
```

I have done "Invalidate Caches", "Clean Build", and "Rebuild Project" in Android Studio several times now. I have also deleted the .idea directory and reopened the project in Android Studio.

On the command line, I have run "ionic build", "ionic cap sync" and "ionic cap open android" to rebuild the project. No matter what I do, it keeps coming back with that same error. Any suggestions on how to get Android Studio to detect changes in my AndroidManifest.xml file, or any other suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: `File: http://localhost/main.js` ??? What are you messing up File class and http protocol? Where does this come from? You are mixing unrelated stuff.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. This is literally what the output in my logs in Android Studio says in the error.

Comment: Can be. But which code did cause those logs? And what is your code or the user trying to do? As using http protocol had nothing to do with storage permissions or a file picker. Explain please.

Comment: The code that caused the problem was the line:

await Filesystem.requestPermissions(); // Requesting Permissions

I no longer ask for the permissions and I just call:

const file = await FilePicker.pickImages({
          multiple: false,
        });

Answer (score 0):

On an Android 13 device you will not use and ask those READ and WRITE permission.

Your app can automatically write to all public directories on external storage.

Comment: You are correct. I skipped asking for permissions that worked. Thankyou!